# Blender Voxel Remesh - Why one side of my model is not remeshing as good as the other

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I am trying to voxel remesh my model which has for sides with identical complicated geometry.

When I voxel remesh at 0.01 3 sides come out quite good but the 4th has a lot of holes.  The photos explain better this result. At the start, I had the same problem on all sides so I added a couple of multi-resolution modifiers on the model, and 3 of the 4 sides came out good.

Can someone tell me why? Or if there is another modifier that might help me or something else I could do, please.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to see from the image but mostly because of your input geometry. These box like "artefacts" are expected. As the name suggests the voxel remesher is creating a volume (signed distance field), meaning it's trying to put tiny little boxes (voxels) all over the place, which are going to be converted into a surface (mesh) again. I guess some parts of your mesh are just too thin in order make it work at this resolution so the only chance you have is to up the resolution even further...

Comment: I tried a solidify modifier and it worked but the overall geometry if the ramesh was a bit flawed.  I then noticed that the main hole problem was only the mesh if the tree design.  So I took the original mesh of the tree and recopied it in the same position on this mesh, joined them and vocal remeshed.  Many of the holes were corrected.  Guess I will work on this method a bit more.